# understanding python twisted asynchronicity in terms of operating system

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I'm new to the twisted library and I'm trying to understand how it is done that operations in python/twisted are performed asynchronously. So far I thought that only GUI-alike (Qt or javascript) platforms use event-driven architecture extensively.

*facts*:

- Twisted programs are run in one thread = no multithreading
- reactor and deferred patterns are used: callbacks/errbacks are declared and the execution of everything is controlled by reactor main loop
- a single CPU can never do anything truly parallelly, because it shares its resources between processes, etc. By parallel code execution I mean that the programming platform (python, javascript, whatever) executes more than one sequence of operations (which can be done, for example, using multithreading)

*question 1*

Python could be seen as a high-level wrapper for the operating system. What are the OS functions (or C functions) that provide asynchronous operation handling? Are there any?

*question 2*

Q1 leads me to an idea, that twisted's asynchronicity is not a true asynchronicity, like we have in Javascript. In JavaScript, for example, if we provide 3 different buttons, attach callback functions to them and we click all three buttons - then the 3 callbacks will be executed parallelly. Truly parallelly.

In Twisted - as far as I understand - it's not true asynchronicity - it's, let's say, *approximated asynchronicity* instead, since no operations would be performed parallelly (in terms of code, as I mentioned in fact3). In Twisted the first n line of code (defining protocols, factories, connections, etc.) are the declarations of what is going to happen when entire system starts. Nothing runs so far. Real execution starts then the `reactor.run()` is fired. I understand that the reactor runtime is based on a single `while True` loop which iterates through events. The reactor checks any awaiting tasks to do, processes them, send their result back to the queue (either to callbacks or errbacks). In the next loop execution they'll be processed one step further. So the deferred execution is linear in fact (though, from outside it looks like it was executed parallelly). Is my interpretation correct?

I'd appreciate if someone could answer my questions and/or explain how asynchronicity works in twisted/python platform and how is it related to operating system. Thanks in advance for good explanations!

*edit: links to articles explaining asynchronicity are very welcome!*

Comment: Your premise for Q2 seems fishy: You can't click on several things simultaneously as the mouse is only pointing at once pixel at any given instant, and AFAIK JavaScript is completely single-threaded (modulo web workers which don't apply here) whereas Python can have multiple threads (and despite the GIL, seveal thread *can* execute in parallel as long as only one actively interpretes Python code). Could you elaborate and give proof of this "true parallelism"?

Comment: @delnan there are no proofs here... this is just how I understand things for now. If I'm wrong, please, correct me. Btw, you misunderstood me with the javascript stuff. I didn't mean that JavaScript is multithreaded. I meant that you don't implement any loop like `reactor.run()` (or maybe there's something I don't know ;)

Comment: In a browser, the event loop is in the browser, not in your JavaScript, but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to talk about this without defining a lot of terms more precisely and taking issue with your facts, but here's my attempt:

Question 1:

Try `man select`, which is approximately how Twisted is implemented - it's a way to ask the operating system to monitor several things at once and let the application know when any one of them fires (block on multiple things).

Question 2:

Yeah, pretty much - but you're wrong about Javascript, it's just like Twisted.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Two questions about `Q1answer`: `select` enables the reactor to decide whether a IO operation can be performed or not, right? /// when the `reactor.run()` is fired, then python interpreter comes into the loop and never gets out until `reactor.stop()` is fired (then python gets out of the loop), right? /// and one about `Q2answer` - you say that Javascript is just like twisted. Do you mean that jQuery and other libraries provide a loop similar to `reactor.run()`? Again, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Q1: Basically, but the actual api is "OS, tell me which of these file descriptors I'm interested in are ready to read/write on," instead of "Can I do this IO operation? OK, how about this one?"

That's right - it goes into a loop it never comes out of.

Q2: The javascript _runtime_ is what's just like twisted - you don't get to see the reactor loop, but it's there - it's not in jQuery, it's in Firefox. If you read the source code for a browser javascript implementation I expect you'd see the loop there.

Comment: "it's not in jQuery, it's in Firefox. If you read the source code for a browser javascript implementation I expect you'd see the loop there." - this is precisely what I wasn't sure about. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2):

Thomas has already answered your first question but I'll like to add something extra to question 2.
From the way you phrased the (second) question, it seems you many misunderstand asynchronicity.
Asynchronous should not be confused with multiprocessing.
Here's an example of asynchronicity.
Lets say you have two tasks to complete.
1) Read a file from disk
2) Sum a couple of integers in memory

In a **synchronous** system, these task are done one at a time and we wait for the result of the operation before moving on to the next.
In an **asynchronous** system we start each operation and then periodically check for the completion of each. (This is where that nifty select operation comes in)
See this wiki page for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O

So even on a single core system where in reality only 1 thread is running at a particular point in time, we can still have an asynchronous system so that tasks that take long (reading a file in the above example) don't throw a spanner in the works for tasks that can complete their work quickly (summing some integers in memory)

(As a side note, Twisted does have support for spawning a new threads. 
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/threading.html )

Comment: Thanks for your answer too! Is it correct, that asynchronicity is independent on processor cores and on operating system and on platforms (python, js, etc) and it is just a pattern for running processing inside a program? In other words, given any imperatve programming language, I can implement my own asynchronicity engine/loop and write asynchronous code?

Answer (score 2):

I gave a half-hour talk on this exact topic at PyCon 2012.  [You can watch it online here.](http://pyvideo.org/video/885/through-the-ether-and-back-again-what-happens-to)